Is it possible to specify arguments when running pytest from VS Code via context menu
I want to see more info when running pytest on certain test cases from VS Code context menu.

Especially "Run Test at Cursor" I'm interested in.
When running pytest in the terminal I can give e.g. '-s' option to see print outputs.
Is there a way to change the arguments that VS Code is using with this context menu?
In settings I found the option "Pytest Args"

I've added '-s' there but it is not used.
I'm using VS Code 1.90.2 with Python Extension v2024.8.1
